# Session doesn't work in IE, it works in all other browsers

Tags: asp.net, session, generic-handler

I'm developing a website with asp.net, visual studio 2012, IIS8, .Net Framework 4.

I use SESSIONS to store user information after login.

when user click sign in button, I send information to .ashx file like this:

```
 var url = "SignIn.ashx?username=" + UserName.value + "&password=" + PassWord.value;
 xmlRequest_SignIn.open("GET", url);
 xmlRequest_SignIn.onreadystatechange = function () { ApplyUpdateSignIn() }
 xmlRequest_SignIn.send(null);
```

**SignIn.ashx:**

```
  ... // check login information and then
  HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"] = username.toString();
  ...
```

Now in every page of my website, I check this session to authenticate the user in ajax:

```
var url = "CheckMemberAccount.ashx";
xmlRequest_member.open("GET", url);
xmlRequest_member.onreadystatechange = function () { ApplyUpdateGetMemberAccount() }
xmlRequest_member.send(null);
```

**CheckMemberAccount.ashx:**

```
if (Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"]) == "" || null == HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"])
{
    // user not logged in
}
else
{
    // user logged in
}
```

For log out I use ajax too:

```
  var url = "SignOut.ashx";
  xmlRequest_SignOut.open(GET, url);
  xmlRequest_SignOut.onreadystatechange = function () { ApplyUpdateSignOut() }
  xmlRequest_SignOut.send(null);
```

**SignOut.ashx:**

```
 // I try everything to make the session null or invalid!
 // BUT it doesn't take effect in Internet Explorer !!
 HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"] = "";
 HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"] = null;
 HttpContext.Current.Session.Clear();
 HttpContext.Current.Session.RemoveAll();
 HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
 HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Value = "";
```

As you can see I've tried everything to make session null or invalid.
This code works well in all browsers(Chrome, FireFox, Safari, Opera, Netscape, ...) EXCEPT in Internet Explorer !

In IE after Signing out, when I check the member acount with CheckMemberAccount.ashx file, the session still remain valid with valid value as if no sign out happened !

This problem is only in IE !!

note that IE settings are all in their defaults.

I have tried **Global.asax**:

After adding the class, and without adding any code to it ( just keep it unchanged with it's default functions such as Session_Start() ), My problem changed and now I always get null for the session in CheckMemberAccount.ashx ! and again the problem is just in IE !

I didn't find any solution after 3 days.

I'll appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the checkmemberaccount call is being cached in the browser by iE. this has gotten me in trouble many times before. Add a random variable to your Ajax call and I believe your problem will be solved.

You can verify this by using a tool like fiddler. You should see that the browser is caching the GET request. You could also switch from a GET to a POST. POSTS are not cached by IE.

By the way... You should fix this for any get requests that you don't want to cache.

Comment: Absolutely right ! Thanks very very much. Both random variable and POST method work well.